# Displaying Data in Gridview on button click after inserting into database

Tags: asp.net, gridview

Below code is working fine I have a EmployeeRegistration form which registers employee on button click and after registering i also want to display data on real time in gridview. I tried with sqldatasource but its not displaying data on real time. want some suggestions how to display data in gridview on button click after entering data into database

```
string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;

                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spRegisterUser1", con);

                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    SqlParameter firstParam = new SqlParameter("@FirstName",txtFirstName.Text);
                    SqlParameter LastParam = new SqlParameter("@LastName",txtLastName.Text);
                    SqlParameter MobileParam = new SqlParameter("@MobileNo",txtMobile.Text);
                    SqlParameter EmailParam = new SqlParameter("@Email",txtEmail.Text);
                    SqlParameter DesigParam = new SqlParameter("@DesignationId",DropDownListDesig.SelectedValue);

                    cmd.Parameters.Add(firstParam);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(LastParam);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(MobileParam);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(EmailParam);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(DesigParam);

                    con.Open();

                    int ReturnCode = (int)cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


                    if (ReturnCode == -1)
                    {
                        lblMessage.Text = "Email already exists";
                        lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        lblMessage.Text = "Successfully Registered";
                        lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                    }
                }
```

Comment: just rebind the grid after save: `GridView1.DataBind();`

Comment: thank you it helped